# Python Plotly - Multiple YAXIS Legends Layout

Tags: python, layout, plotly, plotly-dash, yaxis

I'm trying to build 2 overlaid graphs on the same figure, one bar chart and one line trend with the below code:

```
data = []

for __brand in df_cumsum['brand'].unique():

    data.append(go.Scatter(
        x=df_cumsum.loc[df_cumsum['brand'] == __brand, :]['day'],
        y=df_cumsum.loc[df_cumsum['brand'] == __brand, :]['ecpm_cum'],
        name=__brand,
        yaxis='y1'
    ))

    data.append(go.Bar(
        x=df_cumsum.loc[df_cumsum['brand'] == __brand, :]['day'],
        y=df_cumsum.loc[df_cumsum['brand'] == __brand, :]['impressions_cum'],
        name=__brand,
        yaxis='y2',
        opacity=0.3
    ))

figure = {'data': data,
          'layout': {'title': 'Delivery Performance Over Test Period (Days)',
                     'yaxis': {'title': 'Cumulative eCPM (USD)'},
                     'yaxis2': {'title': 'Cumulative Delivery (Impressions)', 'side': 'right', 'overlaying': 'y'}}}
```

[image]

As a result, I have something like the above where both legends for the left yaxis and the right yaxis are mixed together.

Does anyone know how I can put each one on its relevant side? Legend for left yaxis on the left and legend for right yaxis on the right? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Plotly doesn't support multiple legends](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668). This is an open issue.

You can hide the left legend items from the one legend you have now, and then use a rectangular annotations box with text of the the line trend variable names to build the left legend from scratch. However the legend won't actually have any toggling functionality in that case and will only serve as a box to display variable names.

Comment: Very thorough answer thanks ! Hopefully they'll make that functionality soon, it can be useful for more complex visualisations !